# qt broken link and environment variable

Tags: software-installation, qt, environment-variables, symbolic-link

I've installed qt5.5 from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt55-trusty). But I'm getting following output.

```
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ qmake -query
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/
qdbus
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ qml
qml: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qml': No such file or directory
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ ll /usr/bin/qmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar  9  2015 /usr/bin/qmake -> qtchooser*
```

Executing `/opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh` is not setting the environment variables for me.

```
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ cat /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh
#!/bin/bash

QT_BASE_DIR=/opt/qt55
export QTDIR=$QT_BASE_DIR
export PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/bin:$PATH

if [[ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$QT_BASE_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/i386-linux-gnu:$QT_BASE_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

TEST=`echo $0 | grep wrapper`
if [ "$TEST" != "" ]; then
   exec `echo $0 | sed s/-wrapper//` $*
fi
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: You probably need to **source** the qt55-env.sh file, rather than simply executing it i.e. `. /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the PPA description:

> i386 and amd64 packages for Trusty Ubuntu release.
>
> Each package contains one Qt module and installs under the /opt/qt55
>   prefix.
>
> **Source /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh to set the correct environment.**

therefore

```
source /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh
```